# Have any investigators requested the minutes of Trump's Oval Office meeting?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, congress, russian-federation, fbi

On May 19, the New York Times published a [story](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/05/19/us/politics/trump-russia-comey.html) which said that according to the official White House minutes of President Trump's May 10 Oval Office meeting with Russian Foreign Minister Sergei Lavarov, President Trump said this:

> I just fired the head of the F.B.I. He was crazy, a real nut job. I faced great pressure because of Russia. That’s taken off.

This quote was significant enough that former FBI director Comey mentioned it during [his testimony](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/06/08/us/politics/senate-hearing-transcript.html) before the Senate Intelligence Committee:

> [President Trump] told me repeatedly that he had talked to lots of people about me, including our current attorney general, and had learned that I was doing a great job and that I was extremely well-liked by the FBI workforce. So it confused me when I saw on television the president saying that he actually fired me because of the Russia investigation and learned, again, from the media that he was telling, privately, other parties that my firing had relieved great pressure on the Russia investigation.

My question is, have any of the investigations looking into the Trump-Russia matter requested the official White House minutes that this quote is from?  There are multiple investigations looking into this matter: there's the House Intelligence Committee investigation, there's the Senate Intelligence Committee investigation, there's the Senate Judiciary Committee investigation, and there's the FBI investigation overseen by special prosecutor Robert Mueller.  Have any of these investigations contacted the White House in order to request or subpoena these official minutes?

Answer (score 3):

### Senate Intelligence Committee (taken action)

The Senate Intelligence Committee [requested to be briefed by White House officials](http://edition.cnn.com/2017/05/16/politics/senate-intelligence-committee-russia-information/index.html) who were in the room when Trump met with the Russian officials. Both committee chairman and the ranking member held a joint press conference to seek a briefing from the White House on what exactly was shared during the meeting.

Chairman Burr mentioned: "Once Mark and I have an opportunity to talk individuals that were in the meeting, that will either confirm our confidence or possibly shake our confidence."

Ranking Member Warner mentioned: "'re trying to go the extra mile -- we owe the White House the chance to present us with the information, present us with the truth. We want to know from people in the room, also want to know if there are these supposed transcripts.

### House Intelligence Committee (taken action)

There have been reports that the CIA Director Mike Pompeo [briefed the House Intelligence Committee on the meeting in a closed session](http://edition.cnn.com/2017/05/16/politics/mike-pompeo-brief-house-intelligence/index.html), though the information is not made known publicly as it is a closed session.

### Senate Judiciary Committee (*not* taken action)

Some members of the committee expressed disapproval should this be true. However, it seems like the committee did not take any further action (that is known publicly).

### FBI investigation (unknown)

It is unclear what actions they have taken to investigate the meeting further as [special counsels usually do their work in private](http://www.businessinsider.com/what-is-special-prosecutor-trump-russia-james-comey-2017-5/?r=US&IR=T). Thus, we won't know if he is looking into this meeting or what exactly he is investigating.